# 'ERROR: QasmSimulator: Circuit cannot be run using available methods.'

Tags: programming, qiskit

I used the following code. Can anyone say what that error is about?

````
from qiskit.aqua.circuits.gates import mct
q = QuantumRegister(32)
c = ClassicalRegister(11)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
ite = 5 #number of iteration

#initialization
qc.h(q[0:11])
qc.x(q[22])
qc.h(q[22])
qc.barrier()

for i in range(ite):
#oracle part
    ccheck(0,1,11)
    ccheck(0,2,12)
    ccheck(0,3,13)
    ccheck(0,4,14)
    ccheck(0,5,15)
    ccheck(0,6,16)
    ccheck(0,7,17)
    ccheck(0,8,18)
    ccheck(0,9,19)
    ccheck(0,10,20)
    qc.mct([q[11],q[12],q[13], q[14],q[15],q[16], q[17],q[18],q[19], q[20]], q[29] , [q[21], q[22], q[23], q[24], q[25], q[26], q[27], q[28]], mode='basic') 
    iccheck(0,10,20)
    iccheck(0,9,19)
    iccheck(0,8,18)
    iccheck(0,7,17)
    iccheck(0,6,16)
    iccheck(0,5,15)
    iccheck(0,4,14)
    iccheck(0,3,13)
    iccheck(0,2,12)
    iccheck(0,1,11)
    qc.barrier()
#diffusion part
    qc.h(q[0:11])
    qc.barrier()
    qc.x(q[0:11])
    qc.barrier()
    qc.h(q[10])
    qc.mct([q[0],q[1],q[2], q[3],q[4],q[5], q[6],q[7],q[8], q[9]], q[10] , [q[21], q[22], q[23], q[24], q[25], q[26], q[27], q[28]], mode='basic')
    qc.h(q[10])
    qc.barrier()
    qc.x(q[0:11])
    qc.barrier()
    qc.h(q[0:11])
    qc.barrier()

qc.measure(q[0:11], c[0:11])

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(qc, backend, shots=10000)
result = job.result()
count =result.get_counts()
print(count)
qc.draw(output='mpl')

```
````

Comment: Not sure if you need to run this on Aer or not, but I tested running it on the `ibmq_qasm_simulator` and it did not throw an error immediately like it does when running on Aer's qasm_simulator. It has not finished running yet, but looks like it is dodging that error

Comment: Job finished running and I received a result, so I believe it should work on `ibmq_qasm_simulator`

Comment: @MatthewStypulkoski can u please post the modified code here in the comments. It will useful.

Comment: It will look a little weird in comments since you can't manually put new lines, but I'll do my best. `from qiskit import IBMQ` first. Then call `IBMQ.load_account()`. Then set `provider = IBMQ.get_provider()`. Then set `backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')`. After that, you should be able to call the job execution part the same way. However, you may need to lower the amount of shots you use, as I think 8192 is the max for the IBMQ devices.

Comment: The circuit creation and everything else can stay the same, it just involves changing the backend you're retrieving

Comment: I used ```IBMQ.backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')```.
but there was some other error related to result and it got resolved when I changed shots from 10000 to 1000.

Comment: Yes, that error is related to the shots being 10000. The max amount of shots allowed is 8192 I believe.

Comment: Yes, thats right.Thanks.Its gonna take an hour or so to execute and run.

Comment: The max shots for the Aer qasm simulator is 100000.